# How do I extract an interface in MSVS Community 2015 (14.0.25123.00)

Tags: c#, interface, refactoring, resharper, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
with JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1.1
Build 105.0.20160504.101434

I'm trying to do an "Extract Interface" but cannot find the option.
I found a solution that said that there should be a refactor option on the Edit menu but I can only find "Refactor" under the ReSharper menu.
I would have expected ReSharper to have increased my refactoring options not decrease them.
Is there an option that I need to set that I'm missing or do I need to uninstall ReSharper?
[image]

Comment: What version of Resharper are you using? It should be under Right Click -> Refactor -> Extract -> Extract Interface

Comment: removing resharper fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is static. Static classes can't have interfaces.

More to the point, all interface methods and properties have to be class instances. Since a class marked static will only have static properties and members it is impossible to create an interface for one. Resharper is correct in not suggesting the option to extract an interface.

Comment: Jonathon, I would have preferred resharper to do what C# did, give me the option and then explain why it couldn't do it.

Comment: I suppose I can see that perspective, but offering impossible options and then explaining afterwards why you can't do that is a questionable user experience choice.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Resharper are you using? It should be under Right Click -> Refactor -> Extract -> Extract Interface

Comment: I was using JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1.1    
Build 105.0.20160504.101434.  As you can see by the original screen image, the only option I had under "Extract" was "Extract Class"

Answer (score 0):

Once I uninstalled ReSharper, it the refactor menu showed back up on the edit menu
 (it wasn't there while ReSharper was installed)
I was using 
JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1.1
Build 105.0.20160504.101434
[image]

Comment: Does that refactoring actually do anything? It shouldn't against a static class.

Comment: This isn't a soution. I've got Resharper Ultimate installed and still get that option. If I remember correctly, when you install Resharper and open VS 2015 for the first time, it asks you whether you want to retain your VS settings. You've probably selected not to.

Comment: All I know is that when I uninstalled resharper, I got my extract interface option back.